# Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Let $N$ be a flat $A$-module. Let $S⊆A$ be a multiplicatively closed set. $S^{-1}N$ is flat $S^{-1}A$ module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization, flatness

Let $A$ be a commutative ring.
Let $N$ be a flat $A$-module. Let $S⊆A$ be a multiplicatively closed set.

How can I prove **$S^{-1}N$ is flat $S^{-1}A$ module** ?

I see inverse argument ($S^{-1}N$ is flat implies $N$ is flat) in some texts, but I have never met the proof of this proposition.
If this is an famous fact, reference(book, pdf,etc) is also appreciated.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It suffices to prove that $S^{-1} A$ is flat and use the fact that $S^{-1} N \cong S^{-1} A \otimes_A N$ (and the associativity of $\otimes$). Incidentally, $S^{-1} N$ flat does _not_ imply $N$ is flat.

Comment: How to prove $S^{-1}A$ is flat ?

Comment: Use the fact that $M \otimes_{S^{-1}A} S^{-1}N  \cong M \otimes_{R} N$. Then use the flatness of $N$.

Comment: Proving that $S^{-1}A$ is flat usually done as follows: prove that localization of modules preserves exactness and show that tensoring an $A$-module $M$ with $S^{-1}A$ is the same as forming the localization $S^{-1}M$. A proof of this can be found e.g. in Atiyah-Macdonald.